# Try to derive the length of curve from first principal, can you guys check whether there is any error on my steps.

Tags: calculus

Given a function $f(x)$ and find the length of curve from $f(a)$ to $f(b)$

Let $s(x)$ is the length of curve from $s(x_0)$ to $s(x)$
\begin{equation*}
\begin{aligned}
 s(x_0 + \Delta x) - s(x_0) & \approx \sqrt{(f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)) ^2 + (\Delta x)^2} \qquad  \text{Pythagorean Theorem}  \\
 s(x_0 + \Delta x) - s(x_0) & \approx \sqrt{(\Delta x)^2 (\frac{ (f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0)) ^2 }{(\Delta x)^2} + 1)} \\
\frac{ s(x_0 + \Delta x) - s(x_0) }{\Delta x} & \approx \sqrt{\frac{ (f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0))^2 }{(\Delta x)^2} + 1} \\
 \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow \infty} \frac{s(x_0 + \Delta x) - s(x_0)}{\Delta x} &= \lim_{\Delta x \rightarrow \infty} \sqrt{\frac{ (f(x_0 + \Delta x) - f(x_0))^2 }{(\Delta x)^2} + 1} \\
 s'(x_0) &= \sqrt{f'(x_0)^2 + 1} \\
 s(x) + c &= \int \sqrt{f'(x)^2 + 1} \\
\text{length of curve from } s(a) \text{ to } s(b) \\
s(b) - s(a) &= \int_{a}^{b} \sqrt{f'(x)^2 + 1}
  \end{aligned}
\end{equation*}

Comment: Nice, Looks fine